# MYSQL Inner Join but with multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM people p INNER JOIN job j ON p.job_id = j.id ORDER BY j.id ASC
```

The above is how I am using `Inner Join` to add `j.id` to `p.job_id` but what if I want to add `j.description` to `j.job_description`?

I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM people p INNER JOIN job j ON p.job_id = j.id INNER JOIN job j ON p.job_desc = j.description ORDER BY j.id ASC
```

but this does not work.

The idea is to add contents from my table `job` to the table `people`

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, there are two possibilities. Please post your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right, this must be the solution:

```
SELECT * 
FROM people p INNER JOIN job j ON p.job_id = j.id and p.job_desc = j.description 
ORDER BY j.id ASC
```